# AS3 How to spawn movieclips onto the stage randomly between two points?

Tags: actionscript-3

My game is a birds-eye view car game where you simply stear the car left and right to avoid other cars. The thing is I don't know how to make the AI cars spawn automatically but just on the road. Because the map has grass on the left and right hand side and the road in the middle and I want the AI cars to spawn just on the road therefore between two x points. All help will be much appreciated, many thanks.

I have this code:

var mc:red_car = new red_car(); 
addChild(mc);

var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 750
mc.x = randomX;

which spawns the object on the stage but I can't get it so it spawns between two specfic points.

Answer (score 0):

Position your MovieClip before you add it to the screen. Use the y Position which the car needs to be positioned in the road and generate a random x between 0 and screen width. Then just add the car to the stage.

```
var car:MovieClip = new red_car();
car.y = //your y position here
car.x = Math.random () * 750;
addChild(car);
```

Comment: How do I make them keep on spawning because it only spawns once.

Comment: Put it in a loop and/or create a new variable for each car that you want to add.